# Does Collections.sort respect the index among the tied inputted elements? (Sorting Stability)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

For example if I sort a `List<Individual>` with 10 people by `Individual::Age`, and I input Alice(3), Bob(5), and Charles(3), will the output be Alice(3), Charles(3), Bob(5) or is it possible for Alice and Charles being swapped in a way that they are outputed in a different sequence than the inputed?

Edit:
Seems that his property has a proper name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-):

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable:* equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

For this purpose, Alice and Charles are equal (as they have the same age). Calling `sort` is guaranteed to keep their relative order, and Alice will appear before Charles.

Comment: Wow, I missed it while reading main Comparator javadoc Many thanks and sorry for the obvious!!!!.

Comment: @user1352530: If his answer is correct for you, please accept it (using the 'checkmark' or 'tick'). :-)

Comment: I was waiting for SO to let me accept it. I went to smoke for consuming those 7 minutes... :)))

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the stability of the sort algorithm: see [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)

Depends on the JDK implementation

Answer (score 1):

This is totally depends on how we implements our comparator(or comparable) class. If you are comparing only age then the order will be same as inserted(as List using merge sort) or if you are comparing both age and name then this will be in dictionary order.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question.

Comment: may i know why @Codebender

Comment: My comparator is a Comparator.comparingInt(Individual::getAge)